# Application of Blockchain in Fraud detection in stock market

Tags: machine-learning, ai-design, anomaly-detection, blockchain

I want to develop a fraud detection application in the stock market Using Blockchain technology, we have some pattern that defines the anomaly for use of supervised machine learning but there is one question remain:
What is role of machine learning and Blockchain to detect anomaly like a fraud?